# Appropriateness of method for spinner

Tags: java

I know there is no `setText()` function for Spinner, but I still don't know how to replace it with a more suitable method.

This error pointed out by Android Studio comes from the `onBindViewHolder` method.

```
    // error: cannot find symbol method setText(String)
    holder.spinnerCategory_book.setText(v_book.getCategory_book());
```

```
    public class BookAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BookAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    
        List<Book> books;
        Context context;
        DatabaseHelperClass bd;
    
        public BookAdapter(List<Adapter> books, Context context) {
            this.books = books;
            this.context = context;
            bd = new DatabaseHelperClass(context);
        }
       
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
            View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_view_books,parent,false);
            ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
            return viewHolder;
        }
        
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
            final Book v_book = books.get(position);
    
            holder.textId_book.setText(Integer.toString(v_book.getId_book()));
            holder.editTitle_book.setText(v_book.getTitle_book());
            holder.editAuthor_book.setText(v_book.getAuthor_book());
            holder.spinnerCategory_book.setText(v_book.getCategory_book()); // Line error
            holder.editPublisher_book.setText(v_book.getPublisher_book());
            holder.editPages_book.setText(Integer.toString(v_book.getPages_book()));
            holder.editYear_publication.setText(Integer.toString(v_book.getYear_publication()));

            holder.button_update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String title_book = holder.holder.editTitle_book.getText().toString();
                    String author_book = holder.editAuthor_book.getText().toString();
                    String category_book = holder.spinnerCategory_book.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    String publisher_book = holder.editPublisher_book.getText().toString();
                    int pages_book = Integer.parseInt(holder.editPages_book.getText().toString());
                    int year_publication = Integer.parseInt(holder.editYear_publication.getText().toString());
    
                    bd.UpdateBook(new Book(v_books.getId_book(),title_book,author_book,
                            category_book,publisher_book,pages_book,year_publication));
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                    ((Activity) context).finish();
                    context.startActivity(((Activity) context).getIntent());
                }
            });
            
            holder.button_delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    bd.DeleteBook(v_book.getId_book());
                    books.remove(position);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
        }
        
        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return books.size();
        }
        
        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
            Button button_update, button_delete;
            TextView textId_book;
            EditText editTitle_book, editAuthor_book, editPublisher_book, editPages_book, editYear_publication;
            Spinner spinnerCategory_book;
    
            public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                textId_book = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textId_book);
                editTitle_book = findViewById(R.id.editTitle_book);
                editAuthor_book = findViewById(R.id.editAuthor_book);
                editPublisher_book = findViewById(R.id.editPublisher_book);
                editPages_book = findViewById(R.id.editPages_book);
                editYear_publication = findViewById(R.id.editYear_publication);
                spinnerCategory_book = findViewById(R.id.spinnerspinnerCategory_book);
                button_update = itemView.findViewById(R.id.button_update_book);
                button_delete = itemView.findViewById(R.id.button_delete_book);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know there is no setText() function for Spinner, but I still don't know how to replace it with a more suitable method.

1 - Go to [the documentation for Spinner](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner).

2 - Scroll down to [the section that lists the public methods](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner#public-methods) to see what's available to you, specifically anything starting with "set". If you don't find anything useful, then look at [the inherited methods](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner#inherited-methods) to see what you get from the base class(es).

3 - Discover [setSelection](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsSpinner#setSelection(int)) which "Sets the currently selected item." based on it's position within the list of items and sounds like what you're trying to do.

4 - Update your code to work with the API you have, not the API you want.

```
final Book v_book = books.get(position);
    
// holder.spinnerCategory_book.setText(v_book.getCategory_book()); // Line error
holder.spinnerCategory_book.setSelection(position);
```

Comment: Wouldn't there be a need to specify the ```getCategory_book();``` method?

Comment: I don't know what you mean.